# Check if any of the specific key has a value in JavaScript array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to Check if any of the specific key has a value in JavaScript array of object.

```
myArray = [ {file:null}, {file:hello.jpg}, {file:null}] ;
```

The key `file` has value so return `true` otherwise `false`. 
How to check this programmatically?

Comment: `obj.key === 'value'`? Also - a `for` loop.

Comment: Without for loop.  But may be using filter.

Comment: If I understand correctly you can use `Array#some()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some. Question is still a bit vague

Comment: How? Please explain

Comment: "Without for loop" --- why is that? You should learn how to use loops before you use `Array.prototype.some` (or other array functions).

Comment: agree with zerkms ... learn how to do such things with loops first,

Comment: I already know how to do with loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `null` is a falsy value you could use double negation to check if it contains *a value* or it's empty (`null`).

```js
let myArray = [ {file:null}, {file:'hello.jpg'}, {file:null}];

const check = arr => arr.map(v => !!v.file);

console.log(check(myArray));
```

Comment: Can you you explain this line, 
const check = arr => arr.map(v => !!v.file);

Comment: @kaws Double negation. All values are changed into boolean value. If it has a value, it returns `true`. If it has `null`, empty string or `undefined`, it will return `false`.

Comment: would be nice if you post your comment in answer in my other question.

Comment: @kaws greg mentioned my comment in his answer, anyways you accepted his answer. I will make a full answer next time :)

Comment: myArray.filter(x => !!x.file).length; will work without the need of map

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myArray = [ {file: null}, {file: 'hello.jpg'}, {file: null}];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i].file != null) {
        console.log(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at map/filter/reduce, there's lots of explanations onlne, like https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-map-filter-reduce-in-javascript--cms-26209

in your case, you want to map:

```
items = myArray.map(item => !!item.file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if any elements of an array match a condition.

```js
myArray = [{
  file: null
}, {
  file: "hello.jpg"
}, {
  file: null
}];
var result = myArray.some(e => e.file);
console.log(result);
```