# count the number of specif key, which has a value in an array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can i count the number of specif key, which has a value in an array of object ?
for ex:

```
myArray = [ {file:null}, {file:hello.jpg}, {file:hai.jpg}, {file:null}] ;
```

output = count of file 2.
output is 2 because there are two files in the array.
**Note: I dont want to use for loop.**

Comment: what you tried a for loop? when the myArray[i] is not null ?

Comment: You already asked almost identical question. Take my answer from the previous question and just filter the false values.

Comment: @Kinduser all OP need do is add `.length` to the accepted answer, and they're done. -- I'm voting to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if any of the specific key has a value in JavaScript array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068887/check-if-any-of-the-specific-key-has-a-value-in-javascript-array-of-object)

Comment: thats not dupe man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this combination of map and filter

```js
myArray = [ {file:null}, {file:'hello.jpg'}, {file:'hai.jpg'}, {file:null}] ;

let result = myArray
  .map(x => x.file)
  .filter(x => x != null) // or simply x => x
  .length;
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What about `.filter(v => !!v.file).length`?

Comment: @Kinduser: depends of what the OP is looking for... x => x will work too

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array and check if file is null:

```
var count = 0;

for(i in myArray){
    if(myArray[i]["file"] != null)
        count++;
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: sorry i dont wanna use for loop.

Comment: @kaws you might want to put info like that in your question next time ;)

Comment: true. i did now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using for loop and if condition

```js
var myArray = [ {file:null}, {file:'hello.jpg'}, {file:'hai.jpg'}, {file:null}] ;
var length = myArray.length - 1;
var count = 0;

for(var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
  if(myArray[x].file !== null) {
    count += 1;
  }
}
console.log('File count is ' + count);

console.log('---------------Using array map-------------');

var mapCount = 0;
myArray.map(function(value, index) {
 if(value.file)
   mapCount += 1;
});

console.log('File count is ' + mapCount);
```

Comment: sorry i dont wanna use for loop.

Comment: @kaws why not ?

Comment: @kaws you can learn about for loop on this site https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: map or filter can reduce the number of lines of code. why use for?